# Relational Yii ActiveRecord for table with composite key having NULL values

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

For storing user-defined bookmarks on some site, I have a table with the composite key:

```
CREATE TABLE bookmarks (
    user_id int not null,
    book_id int not null,
    page_id int,
    ...
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON bookmarks(user_id, book_id, page_id);
```

Note, that page_id can be NULL, and user_id and book_id can not. When page_id is null, the bookmark is set for the whole book, otherwise - for certain page.

Corresponding ActiveRecord class defines some relations:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        "user"  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, "User",     "user_id"),
        "book"  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, "Book",     "book_id"),
        "page"  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, "Page",     "page_id"),
    );
}
```

and a primaryKey() method::

```
public function primaryKey() {
    return array("user_id", "book_id", "orig_id");
}
```

Now I want to get all bookmarks for the whole book for some user. So, I do:

```
$bookmarks = Bookmark::model()->findAll(array(
    "condition" => "t.user_id = :user_id AND t.page_id IS NULL",
    "params" => array(":user_id" => 1),
));
```

It works great, returning 4 records, but obviously, I want to use some related data from books table:

```
$bookmarks = Bookmark::model()->findAll(array(
    "with" => "book",
    "condition" => "t.user_id = :user_id AND t.page_id IS NULL",
    "params" => array(":user_id" => 1),
));
```

and now I get 0 records (count($bookmarks) == 0), although the generated SQL statement selects all needed data, it is just not recognised by CActiveRecord class. Another weird thing is, that when I try to fetch all page bookmarks, everything is okay:

```
$bookmarks = Bookmark::model()->findAll(array(
    "with" => "book",
    "condition" => "t.user_id = :user_id AND t.page_id IS NOT NULL",
    "params" => array(":user_id" => 1),
));
```

What am I doing wrong? How to make expression in the second example return some data? PHP 5.4.0, Yii 1.1.8, PostgreSQL 9.1.4, +32°C outside.

Comment: I've been working with YII long time ago and as far as I remember you should use `Bookmark::model()->with('book');`

Comment: @PLB, I think *Conditions* will be merged, so there will not be a big difference (but +35°C in here so I could be very wrong).
uisky, *book_id* for this rows doesn't have NULL values, right?

Comment: @Boris Belenski, correct, user_id and book_id do not have NULL's

Comment: @PLB, same effect with Bookmark::model()->with("book")->findAll(array("condition" => ...));

Comment: @uisky YII has quite big support team. Ask on their forum or chat.

Comment: both `with()` and `"with"` will do the same thing so the usage is correct. usiky have you checked the generated sql? it's helpful to debug knowing the generated sql.

Comment: Let's see your model's rules.  Maybe you have some rule in the model that's causing records with NULL page_id's to get filtered out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue may be solved in this way:

1. **Add a surrogate PK** to the *Bookmark* table (e.g. auto-incremental sequence).
2. **Remove `primaryKey()`** function.

You may also use more convenient code:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        //...
        'wholeBook' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Book', 'book_id', 'on'=>"page_id IS NULL", 'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN'),
        //...
    );
}
```

Then in the controller just:

```
$bookmarks = Bookmark::model()->with('wholeBook')->findAllByAttributes(array('user_id'=>1));
```

As a matter of fact, with UNIQUE key instead of PRIMARY and `primaryKey()` you use hack  to evade impossibility of using NULL column in composite PKs.
ActiveRecord is a sort of ORM, so any logic in SQL must be translated into AR (Yii automatically loads DB schemas), and it must be correct logic.

If I were you I'd normalize SQL to something like this:
[image: Normalized DB structure]

Because of those are two different types of bookmarks with different relations. You should join them only in view logic, not in relation structure. IMHO